# Git terminal is randomly trying to delete most/all of the modified files during a rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

==== UPDATE: ====

Previously updated to say that upgrading my terminal to the current ver fixed the issue. But happened again today, so apparently that's not the case.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Original Question:

This happens somewhat randomly, but whenever I try to `rebase` the branch I'm currently working on, git will *sometimes* (but not always) tell me I have a merge conflict and `git status` shows me that most of the files I've modified are deleted in the conflict. Actually checking the files shows that they are in fact gone, but after I `abort` then everything returns and it's all fine.

I do this **2-3** times and *sometimes* the `rebase` will actually happen correctly without any conflicts, OR it'll return with an actual legit conflict which I can fix and `--continue` without incident.

---

That's the gist of my problem. I wouldn't have thought anything of it, if it had only happened once or twice but it's happening more and more to the point that now about **80%** of the time I run into this when trying to `rebase` and its affecting my turnaround time (and sanity).

I'm definitely not a git guru, so I don't really understand where the root of the issue might be but my best guess its there's some sort of race-condition happening. Up until now, I've just tried using `git gc` (sometimes `--aggressive`) but I'm pretty doubtful that its having much if any impact on how often this is occurring.

I'm usually switching work between anywhere from **10-15** branches at any given time. The upstream/master I'm rebasing off of gets somewhere between **5-30** merges per day, depending on how busy things are. I have no idea if these details are relevant to my problem, but there ya go.

---

Sorry if that's a little long-winded... just trying to make sure I include enough information to illustrate my issue.

Thanks.

========== In response to torek ==========

- You mentioned that there could be a problem when files/folders have been *actually* deleted or renamed on either end. If I have a branch where I've modified 6 files, my merge conflict will indicate that 5 of the 6 (or all 6 files) have been deleted during the conflict, but I can verify after `abort` that none of the files have been deleted or renamed on either end. *Although*, it did make me think about that 3rd *reference* commit you mentioned (the closest converge point). If there was a problem fetching *that* commit, could it cause some sort interference during the process that git might interpret as all the files being deleted?
- Although I can't speak directly to the "discipline" of the team's merging habits, I'm inclined to say things are pretty tidy. I can also say that as far as I know, I'm the only member of the 10-person team experiencing these problems, *and* I didn't have any of these issues up until a couple months ago.

=========== More notes ===========

When we submit a pull request against the master branch, company policy is that our PRs always only contain a single commit. So we simply amend our commits while working rather rather than stacking multiple commits onto a branch.

That just means that during `rebase` after git rewinds, it's only going to replay the current/most-recent commit from the work branch. There aren't multiple commits that need to be reapplied, virtually ever.

---

**I should reiterate one more time as well, that if the "*everything was deleted*" conflict arises, I do something kinda like this:
`abort`, `rebase`, conflict, `abort`, `rebase`, conflict, `abort`, `rebase`, "SUCCESS".** That's how I'm currently resolving the issue, so I'm pretty sure there is "something strange is going on".

Comment: Would `git rerere` help? (https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67)

Comment: I hadn't heard of `rerere` before, but the issue doesn't seem to be related to any particular branch or changes. So I wouldn't actually know how to apply it toward solving my issue. You have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not a race condition (or at least, not of the sort you're thinking of).

The below is long, but it may help.  It won't solve the problem but might get you somewhere.

#### Background: rebase is cherry-pick on steroids

When you do a rebase, you're really doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations.  Here's a brief example diagram of a commit graph, where you are working on `feature` and have branched it off like this:

```
... *         <-- foo, origin/foo
     \
      A - B   <-- HEAD=feature
```

At some point you run `git fetch` which brings in their new commits:

```
... * ... - o   <-- origin/foo
     \
      A - B     <-- HEAD=feature
```

(your branch label `foo` still points to the commit marked `*`, until you fast-forward it to match `origin/foo`, so we'll just leave it out now).  At this point you might choose to do a rebase to make your `feature-A` come off their new tip commit `o`, so that you will have a graph like this:

```
            A' - B'  <-- feature
           /
... * ... o          <-- origin/foo
     \
      A - B          <-- [abandoned]
```

Here, commits `A'` and `B'` are *copies* of commits `A` and `B`, but modified (i.e., re-based) so that they fit atop `o` rather than fitting atop `*`.

To make the copies, you can manually go in and use `git cherry-pick`:

```
$ git checkout -b feature-rebased origin/foo
$ git cherry-pick feature~1  # copy A to A'
```

What `cherry-pick` does is compare the commit you name (`feature~1`, or you could give the raw SHA-1 for commit `A`, or whatever) to that commit's parent (commit `*` in our drawing).  The resulting diff is "stuff you changed to make commit `A`", which git then attempts to apply as a patch to the current branch-tip commit (`o`).  If the patch goes well git makes a new commit by copying the commit message for the original (i.e., copying the message from commit `A`).

If all went well, you then simply repeat the `cherry-pick` operation with commit `B`, so that git makes a new `B'`.

The `git rebase` command simply automates all of this (fully, if you don't use `-i`, or interactively if you do use `-i`): it finds commit `*`, checks out a new branch—technically an anonymous checkout, a "detached HEAD", so there is no branch-name, but it all works the same—and then, again all automatically, does as many `cherry-pick` steps as needed (or interactively selected) to copy every commit, one by one, until they have all been copied.  If all goes well, its last step is to erase the old branch-name and write the branch-name in at the new tip-most commit on the anonymous branch it built.

#### More background: cherry-pick can do a merge

In your case, though, you are getting a merge conflict.  You might wonder how that could be, since you're doing a cherry-pick and not a merge.  (Yes, you're doing a rebase ... but your rebase is doing a cherry-pick, so we might as well talk about it that way.)  The trick here is that git can see *three* commits, not just two, so if the patch might not apply, git can do a three-way merge.

In particular, going back to our graph and considering the cherry-pick step to make commit `A'`, these are our three commits, `*`, `A`, and `o`:

```
... * ... - o   <-- HEAD
     \
      A
```

Commit `*` is the "merge base" of the three-way merge.  That is, it's the nearest point where the two branches converge.  (In this case it's also the parent of `A`, but we'll see that when we hit `B`, that's not true any more.)

Git has done `git diff merge-base A` to figure out what changes *you* made, but it also does `git diff merge-base o` to figure out what changes *they* made.  Then, if you and they made the *exact same* change, git drops that change from what it's doing: that change is not needed in order to create commit `A'`, and in fact, commit `A'` itself might not be needed at all.

For simplicitly, let's say that `A'` is needed, and all goes well and we move on to copying `B`:

```
              A'  <-- HEAD
             /
... * ... - o
     \
      A - B
```

Here, while cherry-picking `B`, git compares `A` vs `B` and goes to apply this to `A'`.  If something goes wrong during the apply, git finds the merge-base of `B` and `A'`: that's commit `*` again.  It then does:

```
git diff merge-base A'
```

to see if it can drop some changes from the `A`-to-`B` patch due to them being contained in `A'` already.  (I'm not sure if git compares the merge-base to `B` here; it's not strictly required, the way it was to get the initial change-set for `A`.  I imagine it depends on how the code is written internally.)

#### On to your actual problem

You're getting a merge conflict, and then git says some files are deleted.  It must be claiming they are deleted on one side of the merge, and modified on the other; what I can't tell is which side.  But the crux is that git is doing a three-way merge: it's comparing the merge-base to the tip-most commit at the point of the conflict, and the result of this comparison is that git is deciding that some file was deleted.

For this to be the case, the file really does have to be deleted ... sort of.  The problem here is most likely that git will sometimes detect renames, but it uses heuristics and it may well pick the wrong candidates.

Let's say that between a merge-base `MB` and some commit `X`, there was some shuffling of files, so that `dir1/file1` became `dir2/file2`, and `dir3/file3` was actually deleted.  However, a lot of what was in `dir3/file3` was moved to `dir2/file2`.

Git will discover that `MB` had two files, `dir1/file1` and `dir3/file3`, while `X` has just one, `dir2/file2`.  Which file was renamed and which was deleted-but-had-its-content-moved?  Git picks this heuristically, and it *may* get it wrong.  Moreover, it may change its idea if you have it compare `MB` to the commit just before or after `X`, if `dir2/file2` changes a bit.  **Git does not look at the *evolution path* from `MB` to `X`, it just looks directly at `MB` vs `X`.**  Or to put it another way, the diff is purely pair-wise, from "starting point commit" to "ending point commit".  This means the choice of what was "renamed" and what was "deleted" can be pretty arbitrary and does not have to match the overall development history.

Another possible source of merge issues lies in the selection of a merge-base.  You mentioned:

> The upstream/master I'm rebasing off of gets somewhere between 5-30 merges per day, depending on how busy things are.

If, when the problem occurs, your next attempt (that behaves differently and maybe succeeds this time) happens *after* your upstream has had another merge, it's at least somewhat likely that git has found a different merge-base candidate for your work vs the upstream work.

The graphs I drew above are quite simple and there's only one sensible merge base.  Real graphs can be very messy, especially if your upstream is undisciplined and allows a lot of branch crossings.  In a complex graph, there can be a lot of "interesting" merge base possibilities, and in some cases there is no one single "best" one (in which case git constructs a "virtual" merge base, which may not match any actual tree in the repository).

As I noted at the top, this is not a fix for your issue, but it might help you get there.  In particular, look at the commit graph (in a graph viewer like `gitk` or with `git log --graph` or whatever).  Or, use `git merge-base` to find the merge-base of your current branch and the one you are considering for a rebase.  (Or do both of these.)

Then, with the merge-base SHA-1 in hand (or with multiple candidates), use `git diff` to compare trees.  Set your `renameLimit` and `-M` threshold to the same values that `git merge` will use.

(These have changed over time: looking at the source to `merge-recursive.c` I find:

```
    opts.rename_limit = o->merge_rename_limit >= 0 ? o->merge_rename_limit :
                        o->diff_rename_limit >= 0 ? o->diff_rename_limit :
                        1000;
    opts.rename_score = o->rename_score;
```

Here `o->rename_score` defaults to 0 but is set by `-X rename-threshold=`, and `o->merge_rename_limit` and `o->diff_rename_limit` are set from your configured `merge.renamelimit` and `diff.renamelimit` respectively, and default to -1, so that if you set neither, you get the compiled-in default of 1000.  I have my `diff.renamelimit` configured to an explicit `0` myself, and no explicit `merge.renamelimit` so that merge uses my zero diff limit.)

Since you mention that this is happening to many/most files, **I would bet that a directory was renamed** somewhere along the way.

Comment: +1 for the very detailed response. Let me add a few more details to my original question above that might help narrow things down?

Comment: I should also mention that I read through your whole reply twice, and didn't quite understand everything you brought up (but I get some of it). Not anything to do with your writing, just that my understanding of how git works isn't fully fleshed out yet.

Comment: Hm:  re: *I should reiterate one more time as well, that if the "everything was deleted" conflict arises, I do something kinda like this: abort, rebase, conflict, abort, rebase, conflict, abort, rebase, "SUCCESS".*  This does seem suspicious, but I'm very curious about that "kinda like" part...

Comment: I mostly meant "this is shorthand for what I end up doing". Sometimes I have to repeat 6 or 7 times, and sometimes I check the log in between retries since it seems as though occasionally it will work the next time I try following the 'git log' command. I'm not 100% certain about that though, as it's also hit and miss.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation which makes any sense here is that files which exist in your branch have been deleted from the remote branches on which you are rebasing.  Consider the following scenario:

```
remote: A <-- B <-- C
local: A <-- D <-- E
```

The local branch (your branch) and the remote have diverged by 2 commits each.  What this means is that both branches are identical up until the "A" commit, but do not agree after that point.  When you do a `git rebase` on the remote, the first thing Git will tell you is that it is "rewinding" your branch to replay the changes from the remote.  After rewinding here is what things will look like:

```
remote: A <-- B <-- C
local: A <-- B <-- C [D, E]
```

I have placed your commits D and E in brackets because they will be re-committed to your local branch in the next step.  But for now, you should not be seeing any file deletion problems.  The reason you won't see any problems is that so far you only have dealt with the remote branch, hence no merge conflicts.

Next Git will tell you that it is re-committing your work on top of the rebased branch.  Here is what things will look like after it attempts to re-commit D on top of the rebased branch:

```
remote: A <-- B <-- C
local: A <-- B <-- C <-- D'
```

Here the D' indicates that it might not be the same orignal commit as D in your original feature branch.  The reason it might not be the same commit is due to potential merge conflicts.  One such conflict could be that the remote deleted some files which were retained in your branch.

It is important to note that you will only hit merge conflicts during a rebase **after** Git has finished rewinding and replaying the remote.  Once Git begins to re-commit your work, you can get merge conflicts.  **Also, if you resolve the deleted files conflict from the first re-commit AND you did not delete any common files yourself in your subsequent commits, then you should not see any further merge conflicts due to deleted files.**  If you do then please post your findings because something strange is going on.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I can tell you that the "deleted files" conflict is definitely happening with files that I can verify were not deleted on either the master or my local branch. These can often be core files that would NEVER be deleted and even only rarely touched. But even if I go in and update a string, or add a var somewhere in there, it may come back at rebase time to tell me that there's a conflict because the file was deleted.

Comment: I updated my question with a couple more details to try and help isolate my specific situation.